# Copy New Access client to users

Tags: database, ms-access, version-control, vba

I use a very simple version control whereby I use the "tag" property on the Switchboard to record the version of the database.

On a linked "mastertable" I have a master record that shows the current version.  If this is out of sync, then there is code in the switchboard to initiate a simple file copy of the new client version to the user's desktop.

I can't use any EXE type auto-installers to do this, so had to come up with an all Access solution, but having some issues with shell commands and timing that is causing the "auto" part of the installer to be inconsistent.

Below are my codes for the Client and my standalone "Installer" database (which only has one form that opens on startup and initiates the copy code).  I use lookup tables for all file locations, but will use strings in my example.

**Client.mdb:**

```
strInstaller = "c:\Installer\Installer.mdb"

set obj = CreateObject("access.application")   'previously tried SHELL command
with obj
   .visible = true
   .userControl = true
   .openCurrentDatabase (strInstaller)
end with

application.quit
```

Simple enough.  So the above code just opens my Installer mdb which opens a form and executes the following on open.

**Installer.mdb:**

```
strFileName = "ClientDB"

strMaster = "D:\" & strFileName 
strClient= dlookup("DBPath", "UserTbl", "LanID = '" & MyID & "'") & "\" & strFileName

if len(dir(strClient)) <> 0 then
   kill strClient
end if

filecopy strMaster, strClient
```

The dlookup in the strClient simply looks up the path where the user opened up the instance of the client mdb.  (I record this on every instance).

My issues is that I am not getting consistent results.  Sometimes it will copy the file, and sometimes it won't.  I've changed it to run from a button on the Installer Form, and it works every time, so I'm guessing it has something to do with timing.

I've tried putting a pause function before the kill command, and that seems to help if I set the pause to 3 or 4 seconds.  I originally used Shell to open the Installer, but got rid of it as I heard that it was running concurrently with the installer.mdb code.

I'm thinking it's something obvious, but I've been staring at this for about an hour and can't figure it out.  Ideally, I don't want the user to interact with this form using an "Install" button, but would like it to happen in the background.  i.e. I want to set the `.visible = false` at some point.

Can anyone see an issue with this method, or suggest a better method to push out new copies of the client - and I can't use any EXE install programs.

Comment: First, I would add code to the INSTALLER that checks for the presence of the LDB (or laccdb...) to see if the db failed to close properly.  I also suggest you create a simple 'log' file that creates an entry, with timestamps, and any other data, of what you are about to do, followed by what happens. Do you have one user that seems to have more problems than others?

Comment: I haven't pushed it out yet, as I found the issue while testing.  I will see if the LDB is an issue, but since I'm deleting the MDB almost immediately upon opening the INSTALLER then it should wipe out the LDB too right?  I'll run a test and see if the issue is here.

Comment: I found a quick workaround.  I run the above code on open, and then after the filecopy, I check if the strClient exists again.  If it doesn't exist then the filecopy obviously didn't work AND strClient was already deleted.  I then don't quit out of the Installer, but let the form open (which had my manual Button that called the same function).  This becomes the failsafe if the OnOpen form call fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to use the shell() command. You can use CreateObject, but that feature is NOT available in the runtime. (and worse, it will not work).

The simple trick is ONCE you shell out to the upgrade program, you want to QUIT the main program (since you can’t copy over it while it is running).

The code I use is thus:

```
strCurrentDir = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

  ' path to msaccess.exe is determined here
strShellProg = q & SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "msaccess.exe" & q & " "

  ' path to current dir...assume upgrade program in same folder
strShellProg = strShellProg & q & strCurrentDir & "UpGrade.accDE" & q

If Shell(strShellProg, vbNormalFocus) > 0 Then
  Application.Quit
Else
  MsgBox "Un able to run upgrade", vbCritical, AppName
  Application.Quit
End If
```

In above “q” is = """"   (a single double quote).

So you shell out, and then immediate do a application.Quit. The upgrade program should have a “prompt” like “about to upgrade – ok”. That “prompt the user has to hit gives the main application time to quit. I also useally write out the locations to a text file in the above code - but the above steps to shell() is the main takeaway solution here.

As noted, you can use create object, but THEN if you quit the main application, then that variable holding the upgrade program will also go out of scope (or worse, the main application cannot shut down because it is “hosting” an automated copy of the upgrade application by CreateObject.

So you in practical terms don’t want to use createObject, since this means the main program is “hosting” or “holding” a copy of the upgrade program and the main program really can’t quit.

Comment: Thanks, I originally had tried with a shell and was getting the same issue.  I tried the prompts and pauses too.  What I finally did was put a timer on the "installer" form to initiate the code, instead of trying to run it OnOpen.   Once the form loads, it allows the Client to complete it's code (i.e. application.quit), and 2 seconds after the form opens it begins steps to do the copy.  As a backup, I have a button on the form that becomes enabled on any errors of the code, so that user can simply start the copy manually if the auto-install code fails.   Will test it with SHELL. Thanks!!!

Comment: so I tried the shell and it works good.  I didn't realize you could put conditions on the shell (as in your IF statement).  So that's just checking for an open instance right?

Comment: Shell() is a function - it returns the hwnd handle. If the shell command fails, then it returns 0. So if the shell() function fails to run the command, I bail out with a message. But to answer your question - yes, it simply checks if the Shell() command ran ok.